# DidSelectRowAt not being called in a UITableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm aware that the typical solution to this is to assign the `delegate` of the `tableView` to the `UIViewController`. The problem here is that this is actually a `UITableViewController`. With that being said, here's the problem.

I have `CategoriesTVC` that inherits from `SwipeTVC` (`SwipeTVC`'s super class is `UITableViewController`). Everything was working fine and suddenly it stopped. No clue why.

I've put a breakpoint on `didSelectRowAt` method and it's never executed. Here's the code:

```
class CategoryTVC: SwipeTVC {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var categories: Results<Category>?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToItems" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ToDoListTVC
            if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                destination.selectedCategory = categories?[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = categories?[indexPath.row].name ?? "No categories added yet"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: categories?[indexPath.row].backgroundColor ?? "DA7553")
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: Table View Delegate methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    }

}

class SwipeTVC: UITableViewController, SwipeTableViewCellDelegate {

    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    // MARK:- Table View DataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! SwipeTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> [SwipeAction]? {
        guard orientation == .right else { return nil }
        let deleteAction = SwipeAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { action, indexPath in
            self.updateModel(at: indexPath)
        }
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "delete")
        return [deleteAction]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsOptionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, for orientation: SwipeActionsOrientation) -> SwipeOptions {
        var options = SwipeOptions()
        options.expansionStyle = .destructive
        return options
    }

    // MARK:- Swipe Actions
    func updateModel(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // overridden in VC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More efficient solution:

Connect the segue from the table view **cell** to the destination controller rather than from the view **controller**, delete `didSelectRowAt` and replace `prepare(for` with

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToItems" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ToDoListTVC
        let cell = sender as! SwipeTableViewCell
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            destination.selectedCategory = categories?[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested this. Sadly, it changes nothing. I put a breakpoint on it, it's never called either.

Comment: Make sure that all intermediate subclasses call `super` in overriding methods for example in  `prepare(for` if the `if` condition fails.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I figured it out. It was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I've accidentally changed the `tableView` `selection` to `no selection`. My mistake. it's not the code.